# Does it make sense to use / create / develop "star rating" feature for public / guests / not-logged users?

Tags: authentication

Storing an information about well-known user who voted / rated etc. is pretty easy and works without doubts. It's easy to prevent multiple voting / rating.

What's easy about those who can be identified, looks pointless in terms of anonymous users. Does it make sense to give guests ability to vote or rate a product, if they can always remove cookies on their side / change IP / switch UA or do anything else, that will allow them to repeat (forbidden) action more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you making rating for products/services - then the answer: definitely NO!

You will get the hell, where unfair owners can increase their own rating, where competitors can decrease rating of other products, etc.

You can do tricks like [browser fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint), but most likely all these tricks can be bypassed.